# Stop played sound in android

Tags: java, android

I used this code for play a sound by click on a button.

```
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if(mp.isPlaying())
                    {  
                        mp.stop();
                    } 

                    try {
                        mp.reset();
                        AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                        afd = getAssets().openFd("sound/07.mp3");
                        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                        mp.prepare();
                        mp.start();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                }
            });
```

it's working well but i can't stop sound!

I use `mp.stop();` .but click on button plays sound again!

Comment: You probably need to put your try/catch in an `else` block after your `if`. Even if you stop your audio when you hit that `if` statement and your audio is playing, you immediately start it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when your onClickListener runs, the if statement checks after that other codes run. try to put an `else` statement after `if` you code should be like this :

```
  b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(mp.isPlaying())
                {  
                    mp.stop();
                }else{
                try {
                    mp.reset();
                    AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                    afd = getAssets().openFd("sound/07.mp3");
                    mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

}

            }
        });
```